# C++Mutex and conditional Variable Unlocking/Synchronisation

Tags: c++, multithreading, conditional-statements, mutex

I'm wanting to have several threads all waiting on a conditional variable (CV) and when the main thread updates a variable they all execute. However, I need the main thread to wait until all these have completed before moving on. The other threads don't end and simply go back around and wait again, so I can't use thread.join() for example.

I've got the first half working, I can trigger the threads, but the main just hangs and doesn't continue. Below is my current code

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable
#include <Windows.h>
#define N 3
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;
bool finished[N];

void print_id(int id) {
    while (1) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx); //Try and Lock the Mutex
        while (finished[id]) cv.wait(lck); //Wait until finished is false
        // ...
        std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
        finished[id] = true; //Set finished to be true. When true, program should continue
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[N];
    // spawn 10 threads:
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(print_id, i); //Create n threads
        finished[i] = true; //Set default finished to be true
    }
    std::cout << "N threads ready to race...\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx); //Lock mutex
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            finished[i] = false; //Set finished to false, this will break the CV in each thread
        }
        cv.notify_all(); //Notify all threads
        cv.wait(lck, [] {return finished[0] == true; });  //Wait until all threads have finished (but not ended)
        std::cout << "finished, Sleeping for 2s\n";
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Edit: I am aware I am only currently checking the status of the finished[0] and not each one. This is done just for simplicity atm and would eventually need to be all of them. I will write a function to manage this later.

Comment: Can you use C++20 features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `cv.wait(lck, [] {return finished[0] == true; });` in main thread, but it is not being notified.

You'd need to notify it, and you'd better use another `condition_variable` for it, not the same as for worker thead notifiecation.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you thats an excellent point. How would I manage multiple threads all notifying the main thread?

Comment: Each can notify the same `condition_variable`, main thread can check if all threads are finished, and if not, will start waiting again